# Multiple actions in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a Dropdown that will have multiple functions.

- "Update" takes you to a page to update information
- "Export Form" takes you to a page to export the form

**Both above actions can be done with the current code. The issue that I am having is to allow the dropdown to also open modals through an `onclick`.

- "Delete Course" opens modal
- "View Comments" opens modal

I have using `onchange="location=this.value;"` to open different pages. However, I cant seem to figure out how to allow both `onchange="location=this.value;"` and `onclick` in the same dropdown.

My Code:

```html
<select class="form-control noform" onchange="location=this.value;">
  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">
    <h6>ACTIONS &#10010;</h6>
  </option>
  <option value="edit_course?person_id=<?php echo htmlentities ($row['id']) ?>&session_id=<?php echo $_GET['session_id'] ?>&operation=edit">UPDATE</option>
  <option value="export?person_id=<?php echo htmlentities ($row['id']) ?>&session_id=<?php echo $_GET['session_id'] ?>&operation=edit">EXPORT FORM</option>
  <option onclick="deleteCourse()">DELETE COURSE</option>
  <option onclick="openModal()">VIEW COMMENTS</option>
</select>
```

Comment: consolidate all actions into one handler so you can catch the two extra requirements you need, like the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<select class="form-control noform" onchange="doAction(this.value);">
  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">
    <h6>ACTIONS &#10010;</h6>
  </option>
  <option value="update">UPDATE</option>
  <option value="exportForm">EXPORT FORM</option>
  <option value="deletCourse">DELETE COURSE</option>
  <option value="viewComments">VIEW COMMENTS</option>
</select>
```

JS:

> In js you need to do some try and error thing for redirection and open modal

```
function doAction(value){
  switch (value) {
      case "update":
          //edit_course?person_id=<?php echo htmlentities ($row['id']) ?>&session_id=<?php echo $_GET['session_id'] ?>&operation=edit
          //here you can do your update redirection
          break;
      case "exportForm":
          //export?person_id=<?php echo htmlentities ($row['id']) ?>&session_id=<?php echo $_GET['session_id'] ?>&operation=edit
          //here you can do your export redirection
          break;
      case "deletCourse":
          deleteCourse();//here you can open your modal
          break;
      case "viewComments":
          openModal();//here you can open your modal
          break;
  }
}
```